# To get multiple values from hidden field

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code i have a hidden field it has 3 values.But i can get only one value using javascript.My aim is to get all the values.
JS:

```
function check() {
 var hid = document.getElementById("<%= hidRegExp.ClientID %>").value;
       alert(hid);
}
```

asp.net:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidRegExp"  runat="server" >
</asp:HiddenField >
```

Comment: A hidden field can only have one value. Please show the code where you assign a value to `hidRegExp`

Comment: Hidden fields can only have one value. Your ASP.net control will render `<input type="hidden" id="hidRegExp" value="SomeValue" />`. I'm guessing you are simply overwriting your value.4

Comment: Hidden fields only store one string. You can store multiple units of data by using stuff like comma separated values or other notations. However, much better would be to simply use multiple HiddenField controls.

Comment: @mason i have the value by comma Separated.Now i want to get all the values.]

Comment: That's something you need to include in the original question in the future. I have now provided an answer based on splitting the string with a comma as the delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myStringArray = document.getElementById("<%= hidRegExp.ClientID %>").value.split(","); //splits by comma.

//now do something with the array. Let's write them to the console as an example
for(var i=0; i<myStringArray.length; i++)
    console.log(myStringArray[i]);
```

Just split them on the string. Note, I found this answer by a simple Google search. When you have really simple questions, chances are that someone has done it before and you can find an answer by searching much faster than waiting for us to provide one for you.

Comment: now also i can get only one value

Comment: Then simply use the code you have in your question if you only have one value. But as a general rule, don't store multiple units of data in a single string. Created a HiddenField for each unique piece of data.